# how can i get the size of my vector in C?

Tags: c

I have this function:

```
void receive_message(int sock, char buffer[]) {

    int test = recv(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    buffer[test] = '\0';
}
```

the third argument of the function `recv()` is not working. apparently i cannot use `strlen()` because the buffer don't have a `\0`. `sizeof()` didn't help me either. i'm wishing i can do this without passing a third argument to my function `receive_message()`.

thank you.

Comment: In C, you don't have a "vector".

Comment: btw using sizeof would make sense (if the information could be retrieved at compile time, and it can't), while using strlen is wrong. There's also another possible problem here: `recv` can read less bytes than expected (usually for small packet it won't happen), i.e. can truncate the receiving data (there could be more data on the socket pertaining the "message" you're waiting for); and if it fills all the buffer, reading the maximum num of bytes that can be put into buffer, your `buffer[test] = 0` could cause a segmentation fault, or silent wrong writing access to memory.

Comment: @ShinTakezou would you recommend me `read` and `write` instead of `send` and `receive`?

Comment: First I suggest you to be sure you do not index wrongly buffer: if it is a buffer N char long, then `test` must be at most N-1 (or, be sure that the caller allocate one more char). About using read/write instead of recv/send, I always do so (if possible), but I am not an expert socket programmer... however, you can't really know when all data are received unless your protocol tells you how many bytes you expect. If you are doing "a chat", you can ignore this likely and keep the "one shot" try. Otherwise, you need a protocol.

Comment: @ShinTakezou this is some example server. just for studying. thanks very much for your help (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're hoping in vain; C arrays don't have that much structure.  You need to pass the size yourself.

Comment: [Most] arrays in C include their length as part of their _static_ type information. `buffer`, however, is not an array.

Answer (score 2):

`buffer` isn't a vector. It might look like an array, but as it's declared as a function argument it's actually a pointer. There's no way to know how long a buffer pointed to by a pointer is unless you know it is terminate with a sentinel value (such as `\0`).

It's probably easiest to let the function take an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the size if it isn't zero terminated. You have no choice but to pass in the size as an argument or zero-terminate the string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it. Pass the extra parameter, or use a `#define` in buffer definition and in the use.